# The relationships between cardinal of vectorspace $F$ and its field $\mathbb{K}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $F$ be a vectorspace over a finite field $\mathbb{K}$ with basis $\{a_1,a_2,\cdots ,a_n\}$ If $\vert \mathbb{K}\vert=q$, then find $\vert F\vert.$ I came across this problem on Modern algebra textbook, but I can't find cardinality of $F$,please help me.

Answer (score 4):

Every element $v$ of $F$ has a unique expression of the form
$$
v=\lambda_1 a_1+\dotsb+\lambda_n a_n
$$
for $\lambda_i\in\mathbb{K}$. There are $q$ choices for each $\lambda_i$, so $|F|=q^n$.